# A word for the result of a work

Tags: word-request

I wrote this sentence

> The user first constructs a wrapper by creating several anchors by means of an example page. **The resulting wrapper** is saved into a file to  be used later for extracting data from other pages of the same website or similar websites.

I am not sure **resulting** is a proper word for such outcomes! Maybe "created", "generated" or a better general word?

Comment: Why you do not say **the wrapper** and semicolon. However, I think the first line can be refined

Comment: *Resulting* appears to be superfluous. I *think* what you mean is something like *The user constructs a wrapper by identifying anchors which delimit extractable data on a representative page; this wrapper may then be saved as a file and reused to extract data from similarly structured pages on the same website or similar websites.*

Comment: (+1) Also, **; this wrapper** is really good

Comment: Or, you could omit "wrapper" from the first clause, making your sentence "The user first creates several anchors by means of *a page template*.  The resulting wrapper is saved ...:"  BTW, I am not sure "an example page" is worse than "a page template", but I thought I'd offer it as an alternative.

Comment: @StoneyB Wow, very nice! how much can I pay so you refine my article?!

Comment: You can't pay any of us; we do this obsessively, out of love for the correct usage of the language!

Answer (score 1):

You can either find a better suited adjective, or consider changing the noun:

> - The result
> - The final product